# How to invoke a pointer to a function in MASM

Tags: pointers, assembly, function-pointers, invoke, masm

So I'm trying to invoke a pointer to a function, but I'm failing. Could somebody please help?

I'm storing the function pointer like so:

```
mov pFunction,offset Function
```

I can actually get the call to work by doing this:

```
call pFunction
```

But when I try this:

```
invoke pFunction
```

I get "error A2190: INVOKE requires prototype for procedure".

And if I try this:

```
invoke Function pFunction
```

I get "error A2206: missing operator in expression".

Any ideas?

PS: here is the whole listing:

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
    option      casemap: none
    include     d:\masm32\include\windows.inc
    include     d:\masm32\include\kernel32.inc
    includelib  d:\masm32\lib\kernel32.lib

    Function proto
.data?
    pFunction   dd      ?
.code
start:
    mov pFunction,offset Function
    invoke  pFunction

    push    0
    call    ExitProcess

Function proc
    ret
Function endp
end start
```

Comment: I just found the answer here

http://webster.cs.ucr.edu/Page_TechDocs/MASMDoc/ProgrammersGuide/Chap_07.htm

although it seems a bit crackpot to me...  (Why can I only answer my own questions after 8 hours?!)

Comment: Is INVOKE a macro that perhaps isn't complete in all cases?  Obviously a CALL will work if you don't mind doing your own setup/teardown with it (back in ye olden days, we always did that as there was no "INVOKE" in the assembler).  Also of note, that doc you referenced claims that INVOKE extends width of shorter than expected items.  I ran across a case where that's not so recently.  I had an INVOKE that was causing a crash when it returned.  Opened it up in OlyDbg and found that it was pushing an item (in a 32-bit app) as a word instead of a dword!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the answer here

http://webster.cs.ucr.edu/Page_TechDocs/MASMDoc/ProgrammersGuide/Chap_07.htm

This is what you have to do:

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
    option      casemap: none
    include     d:\masm32\include\windows.inc
    include     d:\masm32\include\kernel32.inc
    includelib  d:\masm32\lib\kernel32.lib

    FUNCPROTO       TYPEDEF PROTO 
    FUNCPTR         TYPEDEF PTR FUNCPROTO
.data?
    pFunction   FUNCPTR     ?
.code
start:
    mov pFunction,offset Function
    invoke FUNCPTR ptr pFunction

    push    0
    call    ExitProcess

Function proc
    ret
Function endp
end start
```

Comment: Link is broken, alternative: http://www.siliconkit.com/rebecca/help/masmpguide/Chap_07.htm